# How to feed multiple input samples to a tensorflow model in C++ with a single Run

Tags: c++, performance, tensorflow, throughput

With the python tensorflow API one can do something like this:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b

sess.run(adder_node, {a: [1,3], b: [2, 4]})
```

result: [ 3.  7.]

Is there any way in C++ to feed multiple inputs to the model with a single call to the `Run` method? I tried to use an std::vector of feed_dicts

```
// prepare tensorflow inputs
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, tensorflow::Tensor>> feed_dict;
for(size_t i = 0; i < noutput_items; i++) {
    tensorflow::TensorShape data_shape({1, d_vlen_in});
    tensorflow::Tensor n_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, data_shape);
    auto n_data = n_tensor.flat<float>().data();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < d_vlen_in ; j++) {
        n_data[j] = in[j];
    }
    feed_dict.push_back(std::make_pair(d_layer_in, n_tensor));
    in += d_vlen_in;
}

// prepare tensorflow outputs
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

TF_CHECK_OK(d_session->Run(feed_dict, {d_layer_out}, {}, &outputs));
```

`d_layer_in` and `d_layer_out` are `std::strings`, "input" is my input layer/placeholder.

However it fails with:

```
Non-OK-status: d_session->Run(feed_dict, {d_layer_out}, {}, &outputs) status: Invalid argument: Endpoint "input" fed more than once.
```

Does anybody know a way of doing this? My main goal here is to improve the throughput.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer and it is rather simple.
Several elements of the feed dictionary are used to set several input variables, same as in python. However the first (or zero) dimension of the input tensor is the batch dimension, which in may case can be used as the time dimension of the input signal.

```
// prepare tensorflow inputs
// dimension 0 is the batch dimension, i.e., time dimension
tensorflow::TensorShape data_shape({noutput_items, d_vlen_in});
tensorflow::Tensor in_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, data_shape);
auto in_tensor_data = in_tensor.flat<float>().data();
for(size_t i = 0; i < noutput_items; i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < d_vlen_in ; j++) {
        in_tensor_data[(i*d_vlen_in)+j] = in[(i*d_vlen_in)+j];
    }
}
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, tensorflow::Tensor>> feed_dict = {
    { d_layer_in, in_tensor },
};

// prepare tensorflow outputs
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

TF_CHECK_OK(d_session->Run(feed_dict, {d_layer_out}, {}, &outputs));
```

This of course introduces some buffering/delay but it gives me around 1000x increase in througput.